# How to implement Conference in Android

Tags: android, phone-call, telephony, conference

How to Implement `Conference` in Android programmatically.
I need to track all the call informations from the Phone like,

Make a Call, Incoming Call, I want to add a new call to and existing active call (Conference).

I found the [Conference API from Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Conference.html)

Which supports from Android version 6.0.

Iam new in android development . I couldn't find any sample/blog for conference.

Could any body help me to find the same.